# Creating a new model object populating a form

Tags: python, html, django

I made another post about this before but I think I explained myself wrong.
I have my class called 'Empresa'. Users of the webpage can sign their own company up ('Empresa') by populating a ModelForm in a view.
The problem is that I can't find the syntaxis anywhere.
I have:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class EmpresaManager(models.Manager):
    def create_empresa(self):
        empresa = self.create()
        return empresa


class Empresa(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, default='000')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='Sin nombre')
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, default='email@empresa.com')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='Sin direccion')
    localidad = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='Sin localidad')
    codDgi = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    docDgi = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
    sIva = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default='1')
    mesCierre = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    fecIni = models.DateField(null=True)
    ruca = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    novedad = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, default='')
    fecNovedad = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ultVersion = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default='')
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True)
    habilitado = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default='S')
    codEmpresa = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True)
    codComp = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, default='')

    objects = EmpresaManager()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Empresa


class RegistroEmpresaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = ["nombre", "docDgi", "email"]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Empresa.forms import RegistroEmpresaForm
from Empresa.models import Empresa
from django.http import HttpResponse


def registrado(request):
    form = RegistroEmpresaForm(request.POST or None)
    titulo = "Registro SIG | ERZ Software"
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "titulo": titulo,
    }
    empresa = Empresa.objects.create_empresa()
    empresa.nombre = form.cleaned_data.get('nombre')
    empresa.docDgi = form.cleaned_data.get('docDgi')
    empresa.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    empresa.save(nombre=empresa.nombre, docDgi=empresa.docDgi, email=empresa.email)
    return HttpResponse("Gracias por registrarse.")


def registro(request):
    form = RegistroEmpresaForm(request.POST or None)
    titulo = "Registro SIG | ERZ Software"
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "titulo": titulo,
    }
    return render(request, "registro.html", context)
```

registro.html: (part of)

```
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/SIG.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
  {% block content %}
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="registrado" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">{%  csrf_token %}
    <img class="mb-4" src="/docs/4.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Panel de registro</h1>
    {{ form }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Registrarme</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; ERZSoftware 2019 - Todos los derechos reservados</p>
</form>
  {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there's something I'm doing wrong with my view, the problem is that I can't find the syntaxis.
**I know how to populate a view with a ModelForm**, but I can't create a new empresa object with the populated data in the ModelForm.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model:

Also note that you should be using the same view for the GET and POST requests - the canonical "form" view function in django looks like:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          my_instance = form.save()
          # you can redirect wherever you want, 
          # as long as you redirect - cf 
          # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
          # You may also want to use tyhe messages framework
          # to notify the user the action has been succesful
          return redirect(my_instance.get_absolute_url()) 
   else: 
      # GET method, provide an empty form
      form = MyModelForm()
   return render(request, "mytemplate.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: @GonzaloD'ambra post in comments is totally unreadable. Please either edit your question with the new code (do not erase the previous one else nobody would be able to make sense of the question and answers), or post a new question. Also, if your form is not valid, you should see the errors messages in your template (assuming it's properly writen).